# Free Context Menu Editor for Windows 10

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-10

I have quite a bit of programs on my PC and some of them put annoying context menu entries on my right click menu, for instance Super Anti Spyware and TeraCopy. I would like to be able to remove these entries from my right-click menu. My requirements are,

- Gratis (Free or Open Source)
- Works with Windows 10
- You have personally tried it (I used a few so far that don't work with Windows 10)

Again, I would like to remove such entries as TeraCopy, SuperAntiSpyware, Tortoise, Git, FileSeek, and Open with code

[image: My Context Menu]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I found what I'm looking for, it's called [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) (Shell Extensions Manager) and it was able to get to entries that programs like [Easy Context menu](http://www.sordum.org/7615/easy-context-menu-v1-6/) was not able to get to. It meets my requirements of being,

- Free
- Works with Windows 10
- I have tried it

## [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)

> Shell Extensions are in-process COM objects which extend the abilities
> of Windows operating system. Most shell extensions are automatically
> installed by the operating system, but there are also many other
> applications that install additional shell extension components. For
> example: If you install WinZip on your computer, you'll see a special
> WinZip menu when you right-click on a Zip file. This menu is created
> by adding a shell extension to the system.
>
> [image: ShExView UI]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FileMenu Tools](https://www.lopesoft.com/index.php/en/).

> FileMenu Tools is an application which lets you customize the context
> menu of Windows Explorer. The application adds built-in utilities to
> perform operations on files and folders and adds custom commands which
> let you run external applications, copy/move to a specific folder or
> delete specific file types. With FileMenu Tools, you also can
> customize the "Send to..." submenu, and either enable or disable
> context-menu commands added by other applications.