# Tool for moving Windows context menu entries into configurable submenus

Tags: windows, menu

I am using Windows 10 Pro and I am looking for a tool to clean up my various context menus, but not by disabling items, but by moving them into different submenus.

I remember I used such a tool a long time ago (I think it was Windows 7 back then) but I don't remember how it was called. It was some software which added various things to context menus, such as "Run with parameters", but it also had an easy way to move existing items into custom subfolders - in any shell context menu (not just from files, even the taskbar's) I could select a customize option and then I could manage the items to submenus, and it was applied to all context menu items with the same name or so later.

I googled a lot already but I find only tools which either *add* a submenu with tools of their own, or allow disabling existing items, but not moving them into submenus easily.

Does anybody know this software or another one which allows me to do that?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.maketecheasier.com/5-free-tools-to-manage-the-context-menu-in-windows/ - haven;t tried any so can't honestly recommend.

Comment: [Related](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24848/free-context-menu-editor-for-windows-10), but not duplciate. It does not explicitly mention sub-menus, but answer there might be worth exploring.